# Using tocloft with custom titles

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I'm using the tocloft package to edit the spacing between entries in my Table of Contents, as follows:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}
```

This produces the desired effect, however I'd like to customize the format of the titles of my chapters, which currently look like this:

```
Chapter 1
Foo
```

To look like this:

```
1. Foo
```

As far as I can tell, I need to pass the `titles` option to tocloft, to prevent it from overriding the title format for the Table of Contents.

Unfortunately, this disables the `\cftbefore*` commands. Is there any way around this?

I've looked into replacing tocloft with titletoc, as this would let me use titlesec for the titles, but I can't seem to figure how to replicate the same effect (namely different amounts of spacing between different sections)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.